# How to delimit a variable name in a string

Tags: xslt, variables, csv

I want to set the attribute ref_id with "_0" suffixed, but

```
<xsl:attribute name="ref_id" select="$id_0" />
```

is parsed as variable name: id_0, not variable name id, plus string _0.

How to I nail this one down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<xsl:attribute name="ref_id" select="concat($id, '_0')" />`

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:attribute name="ref_id"><xsl:value-of select="$id"/>_0</xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

And of course if the xsl:attribute is a child of a literal result element then you can do

`<e ref_id="{$id}_0">`